# Angular movement in page like on touch devices

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, charts

I am trying to implement an echart treemap in my angular application like in this example:
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=treemap-drill-down&edit=1&reset=1&lang=ts

I noticed that I can "move" the chart like on touch devices, which I am not able to achieve. When inspecting the page, I saw that it uses an iframe in which the chart seems to be rendered.

How can I achieve the same? Is this some special option for iframes? Do you maybe have an example how to accomplish the same? Or is this simply some clever hard coded eventhandler/ translation functionality with ts/js?